How can I determine dynamically the expected type for a widget option in tkinter? (eg. int for a width, str for a text...)
I wonder if there is a way to get the expected type for the value of an option in a tkinter.Widget.__init__ method.
I can get every expected type of values for a specific __init__ method from Pylance, here is ttk.Frame.__init__ for example:
def __init__(
    self: Frame,
    master: Misc | None = None,         # master needs a Misc object
    *,
    border: _ScreenUnits = ...,         # border needs a value in _ScreenUnits
    borderwidth: _ScreenUnits = ...,    # etc.
    class_: str = "",
    cursor: _Cursor = "",
    height: _ScreenUnits = 0,
    name: str = ...,
    padding: _Padding = ...,
    relief: _Relief = ...,
    style: str = "",
    takefocus: _TakeFocusValue = "",
    width: _ScreenUnits = 0
) -> None

(I get this when my mouse is over ttk.Frame.__init__).

I can get all the valid options with ttk.Frame().configure(), but I don't know if I can get dynamically the expected type of values for them.
I want to do this for every option of every tkinter and ttk widget, and it would be really annoying and time-consuming to copy and paste everything.
Is there any way to get them dynamically?

There are no type hints, you would need to write them first.

BTW: The values from Pylance obviously are a little bit weird
